# How To Save Parsed JSON to SQLite Android

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite

I'm making an android application which get data (text and images) from a JSON file on a server.

Everything fine, I am able to parse the data and show it in my application.

Now I would like to that my application is availble offline (so 1 startup = download data, save it on device)

I do not know how to start here. Where and how do I Save my parsed JSON-Objects and how do I Read them out from  SQLite database on the device afterwards rather than from server again?

I Do not need the user to do inputs, Just reading out from server file and put it in local DB on device for offline using

Any suggestions please?

Comment: One of the best tutorials I have seen on SQLite and Content Providers for Android. This can be a good start http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: @hugohabel: The tutorial that you have given as reference is good but it does not even contain the word 'json' in its entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by two ways:

1. By storing json-objects into a file and then saving file on internal/external storage. if security is concerned then you must use internal storage which will be saved on location: 
   /data/data//files/
2. By storing json object in database whose location will be /data/data//databases/. if your json-object is big then you can use BLOB type for that column.

Hope it will help you.